# Can you use a sandbox test account with a standard paypal account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Can you use a sandbox test account with a PayPal Payments Standard account or do you need to have a PayPal Payments Pro account?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Sandbox accounts are for sandbox environment **only**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can and no you don't need a business account.

### Steps

1. Log into https://developer.paypal.com/
2. Click **Create Account**
3. Choose **Personal**
4. Finish process

See [PayPals developer documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_create-accounts/) for more information.